# Practice Superposing Fields Integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, calculus

I've been doing practice problems from Andrew Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics as I have an exam next week. I am having a bit of difficulty following this integral in the solution's manual:
[image]

How do you get from the first to second line?

Comment: Hint: Start from the second line and see if you can get to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to take the differential in line two inside the integral. The derivative of the integrand in line two is the integrand of line one. There seems to be a typo in the $\epsilon_0$ though.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I didn't notice that... haha.